# is DIAMETER-EAP Authentication method mutual or one way?

Tags: rfc, radius, ieee-802.1x

i'm studying the DIAMETER-EAP authentication method and i would like to know if this method can be considered mutual authentication or "one way" authentication.

In my opinion this is one way because the unauthenticated devices automatically gains trust in the server and then communicates it's identity but i can't find anything about it.

In the official RFC 4072 it says that this is an "end to end authentication protocol" but it does not specify if this is mutual, one way or three way.

Thank you.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

See [RFC 4072](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4072) *1. Introduction*:

> In the Diameter EAP application, authentication occurs between the
> EAP client and its home Diameter server.  This **end-to-end
> authentication** reduces the possibility for fraudulent authentication,
> such as replay and man-in-the-middle attacks.  End-to-end
> authentication also provides a **possibility for mutual authentication**,
> which is not possible with PAP and CHAP in a roaming PPP environment.